# What does ':..' mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, constructor, infix-notation

I'm reading a following datatype:

```
data Ne
  = NVar Id
  | Ne :.. (Clos Term)
  | NSplit Ne (Bind (Bind (Clos Term)))
  | NCase Ne (Clos [(Label, Term)])
  | NForce Ne
  | NUnfold Ne (Bind (Clos Term))
  deriving (Show, Eq)
```

What is **:..** in the second member declaration?

Answer (score 20):

The name of a constructor can either be alpha-numeric starting with a capital letter or symbolic starting with a colon. In the latter case the operator will be used infix just like infix functions.

So `:..` is an infix constructor for the `Ne` type, which takes an argument of type `Ne` (left operand) and one of type `Clos Term` (right operand).

Answer (score 12):

`:..` is one of the constructors for the algebraic datatype `Ne`. A constructor name consisting of punctuation and starting with `:` becomes an infix operator. Try this:

```
module Main where

data List a = Nil
            | a :.. (List a)
            deriving Show

main = print (1 :.. (2 :.. Nil))
```